# Whitespace with adjacent selectors

Tags: css, whitespace

I have a list of checkboxes and labels.  Depending on the line item width, and the container wrap, the checkbox may end up on the previous line, with the label starting the 2nd line.    I'd like for this to not happen, instead taking the checkbox with the label to the next line.

I attempted to use the `~` selector and I can reference the label this way (as denoted by the border) however the input is not affected which doesn't stop the line break from wrapping.

```
<ul>
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>AAAAAA</label>
</li>
 <li>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>AAAAAA</label>
</li>
...
</ul>
```

Css

```
ul { list-style: none; }
ul li { display: inline; }
ul li input ~ label {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

[image: Whitespace nowrap not functioning as desired]

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rd1hqjsq/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rd1hqjsq/1/ `inline-block` instead of `inline` .

Comment: Well that was easy :)   Put it in as an answer so i can give you points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `inline-block` instead of `inline` for the display property on the `li` items:

> The element generates a block element box that will be flowed with surrounding content as if it were a single inline box (behaving much like a replaced element would).

```css
ul { list-style: none; }
ul li { display: inline-block; }

ul li input ~ label {
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px solid #555;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label>AAAAAA</label>
    </li>
     <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label>AAAAAA</label>
    </li>
     <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label>AAAAAA</label>
    </li>
     <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label>AAAAAA</label>
    </li>
     <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label>AAAAAA</label>
    </li>
     <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label>AAAAAA</label>
    </li>
     <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
        <label>AAAAAA</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

If you use `inline-block` take in care that generates a white-space between items that you may need to remove. Read this article for more info:

#### [Fighting Space Between Inline-block elements](https://www.google.com.co/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcss-tricks.com%2Ffighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements%2F&ei=4ireVNahI4m3yATdnYHwCw&usg=AFQjCNHFsu1LJ0tIPeU4UCWYVWCEo_6p3w&sig2=n6rzBxezGzPWwvVvBP_o6A&bvm=bv.85970519,d.aWw)